# boost::graph compilation issue with dynamic_properties and write_graphviz

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

This question is about boost::graph and how to handle properties associated to vertices (and/or edges). I am quite confused about handling this, but I suspect it could be a template-related issue.

Let's say I have this graph definition:

```
struct myVertex_t {
    int color;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,                   // edge container
    boost::vecS,                   // vertex container
    boost::undirectedS,            // type of graph
    myVertex_t,                    // vertex properties
    boost::property<               // edge properties
        boost::edge_color_t,             // ???
        boost::default_color_type        // enum, holds 5 colors
    >
> myGraph_t;
```

AFAIK, this way of storing properties for vertices is called
"[bundle properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html)"
and seems to be a **third** way of storing this information, although it is said
[in the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html)
that:

> There are two kinds of graph properties: interior and exterior.

Back to my main question. Now, I can instanciate and printout a graph using the "dot" format this way:

```
 int main()
 {
    myGraph_t g;
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("color",   boost::get( &myVertex_t::color,  g ) );
    dp.property("node_id", boost::get( boost::vertex_index, g ) );
    boost::write_graphviz_dp( std::cout , g, dp);
 }
```

[Online here](http://ideone.com/hdutMJ)

This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7747351/193789)
in a similar question, and compiles fine.

Now I want to separate the printing in a separate function, so I write **the same** code in a templated function, just replacing concrete types with template type arguments:

```
template<typename graph_t, typename vertex_t>
void RenderGraph( const graph_t& g )
{
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property( "color",   boost::get( &vertex_t::color,    g ) );
    dp.property( "node_id", boost::get( boost::vertex_index, g ) );
    boost::write_graphviz_dp( std::cout, g, dp );
}

int main()
{
    myGraph_t g;
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);

    RenderGraph<myGraph_t,myVertex_t>( g );
}
```

But this [does not compile](http://ideone.com/4uD5iC):

> property_map.hpp:361:44: error: assignment of read-only location ...

Any ideas what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> property_map.hpp:361:44: error: assignment of read-only location ...

Yeah, sadly the fact that `g` is const there makes the default `property` factory function illegal. Dynamic properties are constructed in a writable way if the model allows it:

> Requirements: `PropertyMap` must model Readable Property Map or Read/Write Property Map.

Because the property map is writable, the dynamic property compiles the writing branch too.

You'd have to take the argument as non-const or manually override the Property traits for the underlying maps (see the comments here ([Cut set of a graph, Boost Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697477/cut-set-of-a-graph-boost-graph-library/26699982#26699982)) for an example).

*You might consider reporting this as a usability issue, as logically, the properties should be const there*.

Comment: Thanks, just tried with removing the `const`, does work, but indeed illogical, thus I didn't even try at first. I'll investigate on this.